# Bootstrap 3 Tabs not applying the a href using URL.Action in Razor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor, twitter-bootstrap-3

I have some tabs in my Razor I have:

```
<div class="page-tabs">
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class='@(actionName.ToLower() == "viewsongamendments" &&
                 controllerName.ToLower() == "songmanagement" ? "active" : "")'>
        <a href='@Url.Action("ViewSongAmendments", "SongManagement")' data-container="body" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Old Track Details">Old Track Details</a>
    </li>
    <li class='@(actionName.ToLower() == "updatedamendments" &&
                 controllerName.ToLower() == "songmanagement" ? "active" : "")'>
        <a href='@Url.Action("UpdatedSongAmendments", "SongManagement")' data-container="body" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Updated Track Details">Updated Track Details</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

But when looking in the source code, its not applying the `ahref` to the tab. Currently, this is showing:

`<a data-container="body" data-toggle="tooltip" title="" data-original-title="Old Track Details">Old Track Details</a>`

Comment: shouldn't the `href` point to the `id` of the div element ie: the `tab` content and not point to your Action??

Comment: @RajshekarReddy that is a good point. So you think an `ID` would solve it?

Comment: the `a` tag must point to a div ie: contain the div `id` in its `href` value Eg: `href="#divID"` and it is within this div where you would render the content of your action, You can use a `Render.Action`

Comment: If this question is about getting your bootstrap tabs to work you need to edit the question. From reading it at the moment it looks like you just want to get your `<a>` tags to populate from Razor (which would probably still leave the `<a>` tag blank).

Comment: @Wurd I understand, I am looking to get the tabs working. At the moment they don't seem to work, I am just looking at adding an `id` to see if that makes a difference.

Comment: is there a reason why you cant use ActionLink, seems a bit simpler than writing the whole html

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I managed to get it working with the code below. I ended up adding a variable `new { songid = fullAccountCode` the fullAccountCode pulled a value from the Model.

```
<div class="page-tabs">
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class='@(actionName.ToLower() == "viewsongamendments" &&
             controllerName.ToLower() == "songsmanagement" ? "active" : "")'>
        <a href='@Url.Action("ViewSongAmendments", "SongsManagement", new { songid = fullAccountCode})' data-container="body" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Original">Old Song Details</a>
    </li>
    <li class='@(actionName.ToLower() == "updatedsongamendments" &&
             controllerName.ToLower() == "songsmanagement" ? "active" : "")'>
        <a href='@Url.Action("UpdatedSongAmendments", "SongsManagement", new { songid = fullAccountCode})' data-container="body" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Original">Updated Song Details</a>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap tabs work as below, please note how the hrefs match up from the `nav` element to the tabs in the `tab-content` element. The `href` is NOT a link to an action when used in this bootstrap context.

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
    <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#home">Home</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu1">Menu 1</a></li>
    <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#menu2">Menu 2</a></li>
</ul>

<div class="tab-content">
    <div id="home" class="tab-pane fade in active">
        <h3>HOME</h3>
        <p>Some content.</p>
    </div>
    <div id="menu1" class="tab-pane fade">
        @Html.RenderAction("ViewSongAmendments", "SongManagement")
    </div>
    <div id="menu2" class="tab-pane fade">
        <h3>Menu 2</h3>
        <p>Some content in menu 2.</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you do it in Razor syntax like I have in my question above, as I belive that some of it is correct.

Comment: What do you mean "do it in Razor syntax"? What more do you want it to do?

Comment: What you have is plain HTML Markup. Its not what I need, I am looking to use the Razor syntax that I have in my question. As each tab loads a separate url.

Comment: You will either have to use `@Html.RenderAction()` inside one of the `tab-pane` elements or load the html using ajax. You can't use a url to load in html.

Comment: @Rob replace the part of `<p>Some content.</p>` with your Razor code `@Render.Action("ViewSongAmendments", "SongManagement")` do similar to another tab content as well.